# If $A$ is an integral domain with a finite number of primes then $Q(A)=A_a$ for some $a \in A$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

If $A$ is an integral domain with a finite number of prime ideals is it possible to get the field of fractions localizing only by a set $\{a^k\}$?

Comment: The keyword to look for is Goldmanm domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes and the proof is trivial: For any non-zero prime, take one non-zero element and let $a$ to be the product of all those elements.

The only prime ideal in $A_a$ is the zero-ideal because by our construction any other prime ideal in $A$ contains $a$, hence is the unit ideal in the localization.